# Qr Scanner - Angular.Child component -qr.component with input included in parent component (ngx-barcode-scanner), close camera event not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, qr-code, barcode-scanner

Qr Scanner -  Angular . as child sherable component  with input included in parent component

I made child component qr.component.ts and included in parent.component.ts

I want to make it shareable component-> qr-scanner ,
with input output.

the problem is when I click cancel from parent it does not close qr-camera:
Can you see the code and suggest if this make makes sense to you and

qr.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="showQr">
  <div class="scan-page" [class.show-scanner]="isOn">    
  </div
</div>
```

qr.component.ts:

```
export class QrScanComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
      @Input('showQr') showQr;
      @Input('isOn') isOn;
      @Output() content = new EventEmitter();    

    async sendContent() {
        this.content.emit(this.scannedBags)   
      }  
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-qr-scan [showQr]="showQr"></app-qr-scan> 
<button (click)="cancelScanning()"> cancel qr </button>
```

parent.component.ts

```
 async startScanning() {
    this.showQr = true; 
     this.isOn = true;
  }  


async cancelScanning() {        
    this.isOn = false;
    this.showQr = false;    

    this.qrScanner.pausePreview();  

    this.qrScanner.hide().then(() => {  
      console.log('scanner should be hidden');  
    }); 
    this.qrScanner.destroy().then( () => {  
      console.log('its bein destoryed');    
      this.isOn = false;    
    })  
  }
```

Comment: Can you include some more of your code that may show better what you currently have and a better description of what you are wanting to get out of this? I am a little confused reading this question.

Comment: Why not do like this:
<ng-container *ngIf="showQr">
<app-qr-scan></app-qr-scan> 
</ng-container>

Then just remove your showQr in the child component as it is no longer used. Because you want it to go away completely or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Yeah , i tried that , but scan content not showing . It only light on camera on laptop